# How to use mockito / powermockito to make an instantiated dependent class throw an exception on a specific method call

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

This is the code I want to test. It's pretty straight forward

```
  class FileHandler {
    public boolean deleteFiles(String path) {
      // mock this to throw an exception
    }
    public static FileHandler instatiateNew(String location) {
      // creates a FileHandler
    }
  }

  class B {
    public void action {
      try {
        FileHandler x = FileHandler.instantiateNew("asd");
        x.deleteFiles();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        // untested code I want to reach
      }
    }
  }
```

I now want to test method `action` and see how it handles x.deleteFiles() throwing an exception. I have tried doThrow, thenThrow and ran into errors (NullPointerException, probably because I stubbed the method wrongly) or the method not throwing the exception in the end.

I am also confused whether I need Powermockito or not. I will now try an approach, where I mock the whole FileHandler class. As I need to mock the static instantiation method I will need PowerMock for that. But I would prefer a less heavy handed solution. Does it exist?

my partial class mock is now:

```
FileHandler mockHandler = Mockito.mock(FileHandler.class)
Mockito.mock(mockHandler.deleteFiles(Mockito.anyString()).thenThrow(Exception.class);
PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileHandler.class);
PowerMockito.when(FileHandler.instantiateNew(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(mockHandler())
```

Which is still causing issues, maybe becasue FileHandler is used elsewhere and mockStatic kills all other usages.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the necessary members are properly arranged so that the test can be exercised.

For example

```
RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FileHandler.class})
public class MyTestCase {
    public void testdeleteFilesErrorHandling() throws Exception {
        //Arrange
        //instance mock
        FileHandler handler = Mockito.mock(FileHandler.class);
        Mockito.when(handler.deleteFiles(anyString())).thenThrow(new Exception("error message"));
        //mock static call
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(FileHandler.class);
        Mockito.when(FileHandler.instantiateNew(anyString())).thenReturn(handler);
        
        B subject = new B();
        
        //Act
        subject.action();
        
        //Assert
        //perform assertion
    }
}
```

Reference: [Using PowerMock with Mockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito#using-powermock-with-mockito)

Answer (score 0):

using mockStatic was not an option for me as `FileHandler` was used in setup and teardown of the tests and this heavy handed approach would cause problems.

What saved me where `stub` and `method` from `org.powermock.api.support.membermodification.MemberModifier`.

```
FileHandler mock = Mockito.mock(FileHandler.class);
Mockito.when(mock.deleteFiles(anyString()))
    .thenThrow(Exception.class);

stub(method(FileHandler.class, "instantiateNew", String.class)).toReturn(mock);
```

Note that it is necessary to prepare class `FileHandler` through a test class decorator and to use the PowerMockRunner. This is necessary as we are stubbing a static method on FileHandler. This is done so:

```
@PrepareForTest({FileHandler.class})
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class MyTest extends MyBaseTestClass {
    @Test
    public void myTest() {
        // write test code from above here.
    }
}
```